# Set UIView backgroundColor with drawRect:

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, performselector, setneedsdisplay

I am trying to set a custom UIView class's background color. The class also does quartz drawing in the `drawRect:`method.

Since background color change does not take place until the next redraw of the view, I change the UIView's `backgroundColor` property before calling `setNeedsDisplay`. I have set a `UIActivityIndicatorView` to animate while the view is redrawing.

```
self.backgroundColor = theColor; 
[indicator startAnimating];
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(setNeedsDisplay) withObject:nil];
```

The indicator is stopped at the end of `setNeedsDisplay`. `theColor` will change every time I need to call this.

Let's say I have a time consuming `setNeedsDisplay` process. I would like to set the background and keep the indicator animation. Currently, changing `backgroundColor` calls `setNeedsDisplay` but doesn't even change the backgroundColor until the `performSelectorInBackground` method runs! Therefore my app hangs and no indicator is ever animated.
How do I deal with this ordering problem? Thanks.

**Edit:** I meant that my `drawrect:` may be time consuming.

Comment: `setNeedsDisplay` is not time consuming, it is `drawRect:`. but you should not call `drawRect:` anyway.

Answer (score 4):

> Let's say I have a time consuming setNeedsDisplay process

Let's not. You have no business overriding `setNeedsDisplay`. I am not at all clear on what you're ultimately trying to accomplish but this entire question seems to be a misunderstanding of how to draw. When you call `setNeedsDisplay` (which, as you've been told, you must do in the main thread), that's that; you stand out of the way, and when the redraw moment comes, your view's `drawRect:` is called. That's drawing.

If the problem is simply that the activity indicator never gets going, that's because you never give it a chance. It too is not going to start going until the redraw moment. But you are stopping the activity indicator before the redraw moment even comes! So obviously you'll never see it go.

The way to start an activity indicator visibly before the next thing you do is to step out to the main thread *after* the next redraw moment. This is called "delayed performance". Example:

```
self.backgroundColor = theColor; 
[indicator startAnimating];
double delayInSeconds = 0.1;
dispatch_time_t popTime =
    dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    // do something further, e.g. call setNeedsDisplay
};
```

You could extend that example by calling `dispatch_after` yet again to stop the indicator after the *next* redraw moment.

I must impress upon you, however, that if the mere act of drawing takes so long that you need an activity indicator to cover it, you're drawing wrong. Your act of drawing must be very very fast. You might want to watch the WWDC 2012 video on this very topic; it gives excellent tips on how to draw efficiently.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I meant that my drawrect: method may take awhile. The complexity of the drawing is based in user input so I am trying to prepare for the worst. Dispatch is also not supported in < ios 4.3, from what I remember. Should I not be using performselector? The indicator works fine if I do not incorporate setting the background.

Comment: @AnsonL if your drawrect: method takes a while, then you need to factor it out.  As matt said, there is an excellent WWDC2012 video on this subject (though in this case, it's about multithreading, not drawing).  What you need to do is put the drawing work on a separate thread (work on a UIImage instead of an actual view?), and then once it's finished port the data over to the main thread to update the UI.

Comment: @AnsonL Reread what I said: don't make me repeat myself. Your `drawRect:` should _not_ take awhile. You must draw _fast_. You don't need dispatch to do delayed performance; if you don't understand delayed performance or threading, you might like to read my book: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch38.html, http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch11.html#_delayed_performance. Above all watch those WWDC videos; I'm thinking particularly of WWDC 2012 sessions 235 and 238.

Comment: @matt Okay, I've looked at the GCD docs and your book. In your book, you use `dispatch_after` with a 0.1 delay. You say that this is to allow time for the indicator to show. But can't you also get rid of the artificial delay of 0.1 by using `dispatch_async` with a custom `dispatch_queue_t` to avoid clogging up the main_queue?

Comment: I'm not "clogging up the main_queue". I'm doing exactly the opposite: I'm standing out of the way until the main queue has finished doing what it's doing (i.e. I'm waiting for the current run loop to complete).

Answer (score 0):

You can update UI only on Main thread, not in backgroung

Try to use another subview with activity indicator, put in on before redraw and remove from superview after